# Can I return an operation as output for a lambda function with if...else condition?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying to increase `a_s` by 1 for every element of list a that is bigger than the corresponding element of list b using lambda.

```
>>> a = [4, 5, 8]
>>> b = [1, 3, 9]
>>> a_s = 0
>>> a_sum = map(lambda x,y: (a_s + 1) if x > y else (a_s + 0), a, b)
>>> print (a_sum)
<map object at 0x01230890>
```

The output I'm expecting is `2` since the 0th and 1st elements of list `a` are greater than that of list `b`

Comment: Are you looking for `print (sum(a_sum))`?

Comment: You forgot to `list()`ify that map.

Comment: Note that the `a_s` is very superfluous here. You're not modifying it, it's only ever returning `0 + 1` or `0 + 0`…

Comment: Exactly, im looking to print the sum of that map after its `list()` ified.

Comment: `a_s = sum(1 for x, y in zip(a, b) if x > y)` is probably the most sensible solution.

Comment: @deceze Thanks bro. Got my output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
print (sum(a_sum))
```

OR

```
res = list(a_sum)
print (sum(res))
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. The output Im looking for is the sum of that output list. Is it possible to print the sum without manually adding the list elements?

Comment: @Samyuktha0511 Check the solution and let me know if you wanted the same. I have updated "print (sum(a_sum))" in the solution

Comment: Thank you bro!! Its working